# Ultrawide display not showing anything while it is found in display settings

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I just bought an ultrawide monitor and when I try to connect it with my laptop (Dell inspiron 7000) it doesn't do anything at all. It shows that I have a secondary display in the display settings and also in xrandr but it stays a black screen. The weird thing is that when I select to mirror my display it does show on my monitor and when I select it as a secondary display but change the resolution and aspect ratio to 1920x1080 and 16:9 instead of 3440x1440 and 21:9. 
Does anyone know how to fix this ?

edit:
More information

[About system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXeQf.png)

[Xrandr output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri3Oh.png)

It is connected using hdmi but displays it as DP for some reason.

The weird thing is that when I added a custom setting for the second display to use the ultrawide aspect ratio but a lower resolution it dit work.

Comment: Edit your question with some more information such as which version of Ubuntu you are using, what video hardware your laptop has, how you are connecting your laptop to the monitor etc. `Ubuntu Settings -> About` should show the info.

Comment: And add the output of `xrandr` while the monitor is connected.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I added as an edit, thank you for pointing out